# btrfs: HUGE metadata allocated

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, btrfs

I have a 256GB SSD disk on which I converted my ext4 root FS to btrfs. I erased the ext4 backup subvolume, enabled compression and defragmented recursively to enable it on all files.

`btrfs fi df /` has an output that worries me though:

```
Data: total=148.00GB, used=106.11GB
System: total=32.00MB, used=16.00KB
Metadata: total=65.00GB, used=2.04GB
```

If I understand the output correctly, 65GB (1/4 of my disk!) is reserved for meta-data and not available for storing files. If this is correct, it would be a huge waste of my disk space. Am I understanding correctly? Can the metadata-allocated portion of my disk be resized?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, make sure your kernel and the BTRFS user-space is up-to-date.

According to the [BTRFS FAQ](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Can_I_change_metadata_block_size_without_recreating_the_filesytem.3F), you cannot resize the metadata block size. You can, however, try to run **btrfs balance start -m <mount point>** which will reallocate the metadata across the entire disk [and, as a side effect, possibly free up unallocated space.](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#What_does_.22balance.22_do.3F)

If that doesn't work, you may have to backup your data and recreate the filesystem. (Take a look at [this](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Help.21_I_ran_out_of_disk_space.21) for more info.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Kernel is 3.11.2, btrfs-tools are v0.20-rc1 so I don't think I'm out of date here. I tried to run a balance but then I hit the following bug:

http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-btrfs/msg26977.html

and don't feel like compiling a newer kernel just for this. :P

What I wonder is whether these 65GB are the metadata block that cannot be resized, or if that term refers to something else. Otherwise I really don't understand how the metadata block got created with that size in the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am only a user of btrfs and not an expert, so my help is limited. In any case, it's possible there is a flaw in the conversion process from ext4.

Comment: So, the necessary patch made it into the stable kernel, and I have tried what you suggested. Balancing indeed reduced the amount of reserved area for meta-data down to 3GB, and the claimed space now appears as free space in 'df'. Note that you don't need to rebalance the whole disk, you can do **btrfs balance start -m <mount point>** to only rebalance the metadata, which is much faster. Thanks for the insightful answer!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: "you cannot resize the metadata block size". This is irrelevant to this question - the FAQ talks about the allocation unit size, not the amount of space allocated for the metadata.

Answer (score 4):

This will decrease metadata size.

```
sudo btrfs balance start -v -musage=0 /path
```

Comment: It works! But how do you explain it? According to [documentation](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Balance.html), `-musage=0` means to "balance only block groups with usage under the given percentage (0%)", which in turns means balancing nothing at all? Where did I get wrong?